# Decryption not working through ASP.NET web application

Tags: encryption, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008

Appreciate help on below issue where we are using a decryption program written in .net from a web application to decrypt and encrypt files on server.

This program is working fine on Windows 2008 server when launched from command line. However when we are calling the same program from Asp.net code in an application hosted on IIS 7.5 --> Its not working at all.

Its not even showing any error. Even checked event logs. It simply does not decrypts.

Please note we are using ProcStart to launch this decryption program and passing necessary parameters. The Keys are well places on server in a local folder and the exe file with required config files is placed in another folder on server. All these folders have been provided full access to everyone right now just to make sure there are no access issues with files when accessing through IIS.
Also, the same program works fine when we run the site in debug mode on server (from visual studio after logging with localadmin).

Please help if we are missing some settings somewhere which are not allowing the decryption program to work when launched by a web user from website.

Answer (score 0):

Unless we have any error it is difficult to troubleshoot but can you try to configure an apppool with some user/system idenitity. Give that identity full previledge on files to encrylt/decrypt and program. Run your asp.net website using this configured apppool.

Comment: I tried changing AppPoolIdentity to a custom account and gave localadmin credentials here. But still the same error. Do we need to do anything else also?